# Python str.index() throwing exception yet substring is there

Tags: string, python-3.x

Despite having a string (rawStr) with a known substring in it ("INA : ), when I try parsing it via '.index', python (3.4) never finds it:

```
print ("Parse:" +  rawStr)
try:
    idax = rawStr.index("INA : ") 
except:
    "Error In String"
```

What I see on the console is:

```
Parse:
CLI >> gi
INA : 0x01777BC0
INB : 0xFC877FF7
CLI >> 
Error In String
```

Since it prints the substring I'm trying to index onto the console, it's obviously there.   But why does idax never get assigned and the exception get thrown?

Is it possible that the carriage return / linefeed at the start of the string is throwing the indexer off?

Comment: What traceback do you get if you don't catch the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your statement:

```
print("Parse:" +  rawStr)
```

just prints

```
Parse:
```

it appears that you don't actually have `rawStr` defined.  Take a look at the following example:

```
>>> ss = ['INA : 0x01777BC0', 'INA : 0xFC877FF7']
>>> for rawStr in ss:
...   try:
...     idx = rawStr.index('INA : ')
...     print(idx)
...   except:
...     print('Error in string.')
...
0
0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my effort to simplify the code I ommited that rawStr is defined before the print parsing.  rawStr has the full string as listed in the console output.

Unfortunately, the part of the code that I omitted thinking it had nothing to do with the issue was where I print where the index was found:

```
  print ("Parse:" +  rawStr)
  try:
        idax = rawStr.index(" : ")  
        print ( "A found: " + idax  )  #<------------
  except
        print('Error in string.')
```

So the exception was thrown not because it didn't find it, but rather it can't print the string with idax via  '+' without a conversion first.